# "Could not find the main class: MineAvtaler. Program will exit." - Only when running outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, noclassdeffounderror

I've made my application in Eclipse. It's fairly simple and contains ~1000 lines total with code. My class `MineAvtaler` contains my main function.

I run this successfully from Eclipse's "Run" button. However whenever I try to run the code from command line, I get the error message in the title. I've compiled as such: `javac MineAvtaler.java Avtaledata.java Avtale.java`

And tried to run the application as such:

- java MineAvtaler
- javaw MineAvtaler.java

The latter gives the error message in a message box instead of in the console.

Why won't my program run outside of Eclipse?

*I'm using Windows 7 and have JDK installed. This is the stacktrace I get:*

```
C:\Users\Codemonkey1991\Desktop\mineavtaler>java MineAvtaler Avtaledata Avtale
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MineAvtaler (wrong name: mineavtaler/MineAvtaler)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: MineAvtaler.  Program will exit.
```

*Here is the source code: *

- [MineAvtaler.java](http://pastebin.com/Dj2MkHRs)
- [Avtaledata.java](http://pastebin.com/7dNT44ka)
- [Avtale.java](http://pastebin.com/GZExCXTU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem of packages. `MineAvtaler` is inside a package named `mineavtaler` (character capitalization is relevant), like stated in the first line of your source. So you probably have a directory called `mineavtaler`, created for you by Eclipse. This is not the directory you created for the project, is a 'special' directory created by Eclipse in which it put your `MineAvtaler.java` file.

You don't have to open a terminal here. Instead, open it on the parent directory and run: `java mineavtaler.MineAvtaler`. This way it should work.

**EDIT**: run `java mineavtaler.MineAvtaler` from `C:\Users\Codemonkey1991\Desktop\`

When calling the "java" command you always have to observe the package structure. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html for more info.